# Do Roles and Profiles in ASP.NET MVC3 need changing when porting to MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-profiles, asp.net-roles

I've created a project using ASP.NET MVC3 and now want to port it to MVC5. It uses Membership, Roles and Profiles to authenticate users, as is common in MVC3. However, I understand that MVC5 uses the Identity system instead of Membership. Therefore, I would need to update my Membership logic when porting to MVC5. That brings me to my question: Does the same apply to Roles and Profiles? Will I need to make any changes to them in order to make them compatible with MVC5? If so, any links to further information would be appreciated (unless everything I need to know can be condensed into a brief StackOverflow answer :P).

Answer (score 0):

Roles are now part of the Identity system.

Profiles are your own responsibility, which generally you implement by using your own User class in Identity.

So yes, you have work to do.